# No Collection being created on call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm running the script as follows

```
const db = require("../config/database");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSettings = require("../models/userSettings");
const Users = require("../models/users");

// code runs which connects to the db
// assume the models are set up fine and properly linked
Users.create({
    userName: account.userName
}, (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`Could not create user with error: ${user}`);
    }
    else {
        console.log(`User created ${user}`);
    }
    UserSettings.create({
        user: user
    }, (error, userSetting) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`UserSettings not created for ${user.userName} : ${error}`);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`settings! ${userSetting}`);
        }
    });
});
```

I run this code, then I go to my terminal and check mongo itself, I have only the users collection made, not the usersSetting collection

I'm just confused because afaik, both users + userSettings are set up the same way, so I'm not sure why userSetting collection isn't made :(.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here's the 2 schemas as requested (a bit trimmed to fit in easier)

Users.js as my model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
const _ = require("lodash");

const generator = require("../security/generator");
const address = require("./address");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UsersSchema = new Schema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, "Please fill a valid email     address"]
    },
        password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UsersSchema.methods.isPasswordValid = function(password) {
    console.log("Comparing passwords");

    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

UsersSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    let obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj.password;

    return obj;
};

UsersSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    let user = this;

    console.log("----------");
    console.log(user);

    if (_.isEmpty(user) || !user.isModified("password")) {
        return next();
    }

    user.password = generator.salt(user.password);
    next();
});

const Users = mongoose.model("users", UsersSchema);
module.exports = Users;
```

UserSettings.js from models

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSettingsSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users",
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    useMetricMeasurements: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    locale: { //tan: make this a enum
        type: String,
        default: "en-US"
    }
});

UserSettingsSchema.pre("save",function(next){
    next();
});

const UserSettings = mongoose.model("userSettings", UserSettingsSchema);
module.exports = UserSettings;
```

I trimmed both files a bit because I figured the other fields were just going to be distracting.

Comment: Does your console logs anything is both calls?

Comment: Can you post the `userSettings` and `user` schema?

Comment: No console logs @Graciano

Comment: I put a trimmed up version of the schemas @Sridhar the fields I purged were set up the same as the other fields, just with different names basically.

Comment: @DanTan Your code snippet works fine for me, creating document in both the collections. May be the issue is caused by some other fields?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that Mongoose is asynchronous. So you might not have the user persisted when the UserSettings.create() is been invoked.
Try moving your insert code right after

```
console.log(`User created ${user}`);
```

Comment: I did try putting this inside the else statement after that line.  Unfortunately, it reacted the same :(.  No console error messages, nor any UserSetting created :(

Comment: Could be something related to some property. Try setting a User with only the _id set and run your code.